# How to filter for multiple possible values?

Tags: r

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
ID   Var1P     Var1C     Var2P    Var2C   Var3P   Var3P   NoDxP NoDxC
101  1         3         3        1        1      1       1      1
102  1         1         1        2        1      1       1      1
103  2         1         1        3        1      1       1      1
104  1         0         2        0        1      1       1      1
```

What I have been trying to do is filter for only the observations that have all values of 0, 1, or, 2. Basically getting rid of anything that has a score of 3 or higher. I'm attempting to use this filter method - it should be noted that this dataframe is in class character:

```
namesnovalue <- dataframe[c(2:7)]
namesnovalue <- names(namesnovalue)
filternovalue <- function(x) {
  filter(dataframe, x == '1' | x == '0' | x == '2')
}

novalue <- sapply(dataframe[namesnovalue], FUN=filternovalue, simplify=TRUE, USE.NAMES=TRUE)
novalue <- as.data.frame(novalue)
```

I think the function attempts to do what I set out for it to do. But, before I make novalue a dataframe I get a matrixing of the data. When I make it a dataframe I get a dataframe made up of the matrices (or so it appears). I'm not sure where I'm writing the argument incorrectly.

For reference, the data output I'm trying to get would be this:

```
ID   Var1P     Var1C    Var2P    Var2C    Var3P    Var3C  NoDxP   NoDxC
102  1         1        1        2        1        1      1       1
104  1         0        2        0        1        1      1       1
```

Thank you all for any help and time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED** based on updated question.

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  filter(across(-starts_with("ID"), ~ . < 3))
```

Result:

```
   ID Var1P Var1C Var2P Var2C Var3P Var3C
1 102     1     1     1     2     1     1
2 104     1     0     2     0     1     1
```

Where data `df1` is:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 101:104, Var1P = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
                      Var1C = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Var2P = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
                      Var2C = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 0L), Var3P = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                      Var3C = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), 
                      class = "data.frame", 
                      row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: This would work but I think I would need to specify the ```starts_with()``` differently. My full dataframe goes on for 66 variables and they start to have different names later on in the data. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Edited accordingly, assuming you just want to ignore the first `ID` column. Obviously the column selection depends on column names, the more important part is the filter across.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can use `rowSums` to select rows which has no value greater than or equal to 3.

```
df[rowSums(df[-1] >= 3) == 0, ]

#   ID Var1P Var1C Var2P Var2C Var3P Var3P.1 NoDxP NoDxC
#2 102     1     1     1     2     1       1     1     1
#4 104     1     0     2     0     1       1     1     1
```